# My Google Analytics funnel has many entrances and exits in later stages. Why is that?

Tags: google-analytics, conversions, goal-tracking, goals

I built a conversion funnel in google analytics. In the result I see many entrances and exits in late stages, even though in my site it is almost impossible to get to a later stage without going through an earlier stage. What can explain such a funnel?

[image]

Comment: I may suppose, this happens because of session length: the visitor has reached the second step, then he distracted on something and the session ended. After that he returned and continue his way. Google Analytics would define it as a new session and make (entrance).